# Ruby On Rails Development Log

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I'm using ROR on a Ubuntu server.
I remember the first time I start ROR use rails s,
I can see all logs, server status in the window
[image]

Now I start it as background function.
When I need to check the log, I need to open WinSCP, find development log the huge file and open it.
The time for downloading the file takes minutes.

Actually I dun need to see all log, I need only view last say 10-20 lines.

How can I do that?View last 10-20 development log without influence the ROR server.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This should work (assuming that you're already in your Rails project's main directory):

```
tail -f -n=20 log/development.log
```

Also, this command is outputting new lines continuously as they appear in log (because of modifier `-f`).

Comment: When I try, it says tail=20 invalid number of lines,so I delete -n=20. This works: tail -f log/development.log